# How to print a 2D array with dots inside them in C

Tags: arrays, c

how would I input a 2D array in C, filled with dots?

Here is the code I have written so far, but I still don't see an output of a 2D array with dots.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PLAYER_NONE 0
#define PLAYER 1
#define PLAYER_CPU 2

int i; // Global Variable for column and row
int j; // Global Variable for column and row

char playerBoard[8][8]; //Global Variable
char cpuBoard[8][8]; // Global Variable

//Initialise the main parts of the board

void initialise_board(void)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { //iterate the rows
       for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
           cpuBoard[i][j] = '.';
        }
   }

   for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
       for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
           playerBoard[i][j] = '.';
       }
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   initialise_board();

   while (!check_win()) {
       display_board();
       get_move(turn);
       turn = (turn == 1) ? 2 : 1;

   return 0;
}
```

//Display battleship board when a turn is played

```
void display_board()
{

   printf("\n");
   for (char i = 'A'; i < 'H' + 1; i++) {
       printf("%c", i);
   }
   printf("\n");

   for (i = 1; i < 8 + 1; i++) {
       printf("%d",i);
       for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   printf("===");
   printf("\n");
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you very much

Comment: You are assigning values, but are never displaying your array

Comment: Hi @Cid, I have a display_board function but is seperate since that outputs the row headings and column headings, if needed I can show it?

Comment: Please show the function you use to display since your problem seems to come from it.

Comment: Can you edit your post and put your function in it ? Thanks.

Comment: Since I edited your post, you are missing a closing bracket `}` in your `main` after the `while`.

Comment: Sorry the intial code I gave already had the existing closing bracket, still it doesnt seem to work :/

Comment: You do see the ABCDEFGH ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, while troubleshooting a seemingly impossible problem, it is a good idea to remove all distractions from the code:

Run a simplified `main()` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   initialise_board();

   //while (!check_win()) {
       display_board();
   //    get_move(turn);
   //    turn = (turn == 1) ? 2 : 1;

   return 0;
}
```

And you will see some output, which you can then debug to adjust as needed.

However, As you point out in your comments, you are *not* seeing output.  If you look closely, you will discover that is because you are never including `cpuBoard` or `playerBoard` in a printf statement, such as:

```
 printf("%c", cpuBoard[i][j]);
```

The following will not finish this for you, but will get you started:

```
void display_board(void)
{
   //printf("\n");//removed for illustration
   //for (char i = 'A'; i < 'H' + 1; i++) {
   //    printf("%c", i);
   //}
   printf("\n");

   for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) 
   {
       for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
       {
            printf("%c", cpuBoard[i][j]); //illustrates printout of populated array cpuboard.
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   printf("===");
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I ran a simplified version as you said, but I still get the same output with the array but no dots in it. However, when I also commented out display board, I get nothing, its blank.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. Check for the opening and closing brackets and add following statement in initializeboard() function :

```c
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) { 
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) { 
        printf("%c",playerBoard[i][j]); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Farah, that did not help :(

Comment: ...But it does address the primary issue of not including the array in a printf statement...

Comment: ...Try returning array from initializeboard function and passing it into displayboard as an argument